# Duplicate iOS kCGBlendModeSoftLight blending

Tags: ios, core-graphics, shader, blending, color-blending

I'm trying to duplicate the CoreGraphics kCBBlendModeSoftLight blending using shaders. (I've already implemented a few other CG blend modes already)

The problem is that while there a lot if (different) description of Photoshop's Soft Light blending, I'm interested in the CoreGraphics' version.

Does anyone know the exact formula used in CG to determine the result of the blend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CG, it's not explicitly documented, but [the documentation for Core Image's CISoftLightBlendMode filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISoftLightBlendMode) says:

> The formula used to create this filter is described in the PDF specification, which is available online from the Adobe Developer Center.

[Here's the page you can get the PDF Reference from.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html) The formula given is (in pseudocode, transcribed by me from the mathematical syntax in the PDF while hoping I didn't mess any part of it up):

```
D(float x) =
    x ≤ 0.25
    ? ((16.0 × x - 12.0) × x + 4.0) × x
    : sqrt(x)

softlight(__color backdrop, __color source) =
    source ≤ 0.5
    ? backdrop - (1.0 - 2.0 × source) × backdrop × (1.0 - backdrop)
    : backdrop + (2.0 × source - 1.0) × (D(backdrop) - backdrop)
```

(For GLSL, you'd use `vec4` instead of CIKL's `__color`.)

The introduction to the section notes that blend modes whose definitions use a particular notation are “separable”, meaning that the formula is applied to the components separately. The soft light blend mode is one of these blend modes, so you don't need to compute a luminance value or anything like that.

Comment: Great! I got hold of some PDFReference doc which described the SoftLight blend but didn't give the exact formula. The linked worked fine. Nice spotting the info in the CI docs too.